# Converting a SISO LTI System to a MIMO LTI System

Tags: filter-design, linear-systems, infinite-impulse-response, state-space

I have a SIMO IIR filter represented as a state space system. I'm wondering if there is a canonical way of converting a IIR filter into a MIMO system, so I can calculate $N$ terms as input at once and output $N$ outputs with the least amount of FLOPs possible.

So far, I've found the following way to do it:

Assume our original SISO system is:

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{B}\mathbf{u}(t)
$$
$$
\mathbf{y}(t) = \mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}(t) + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{u}(t)
$$

and $L$ is our chunk size. Then our MIMO is:

$$
\hat{\mathbf{A}} = \mathbf{A}^{L}
$$

$$
\hat{\mathbf{B}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{A}^{L - 1}\mathbf{B} &
\mathbf{A}^{L - 2}\mathbf{B} &
\cdots &
\mathbf{B}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\hat{\mathbf{C}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{C} \\
\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A} \\
\vdots \\
\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{L - 1} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\hat{\mathbf{D}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{D} & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\mathbf{C}\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{D} & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
\mathbf{C}\mathbf{A}^{L - 2}\mathbf{B} & \cdots & \mathbf{C}\mathbf{B} & \mathbf{D}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \hat{\mathbf{A}}\mathbf{x}(t) + \hat{\mathbf{B}}\mathbf{u}(t)
$$

$$
\mathbf{y}(t) = \hat{\mathbf{C}}\mathbf{x}(t) + \hat{\mathbf{D}}\mathbf{u}(t)
$$

But I'm wondering if there is a more FLOP efficient way...

Comment: OK, this is a strange question.  Because (A) just make the input matrix the identity matrix, (B) for physical systems that's generally not physically possible (i.e., position = $\int \mathrm{velocity} dt$, not the integral of velocity plus some arbitrary input), even when such things _are_ possible then (C) you can't go to the electrical and mechanical engineering teams and demand every physically possible input.  So -- please tell us what you're _really_ trying to do.  Ultimately we'll ask you to **edit your question**, but comments work in the short term.

Comment: I'm looking for the correct way to "block" the computation of a state space system that represents an IIR filter by introducing delay. Not sure I understand what you are trying to say in your reply.

Comment: "Block" as in prevent, or "block" as in compute in blocks?  If you're talking about IIR filters **edit your question** with some background so we all know state-space can be used to express IIR filters, but that's not the only thing it's commonly used for.  In fact, edit your question to tell us all of what you're really doing -- as it sits right now, your question is too broad to really make sense.

Comment: Compute in blocks. I've tried to add more detail

Comment: @TimWescott I think it should be clear now? Let me know if anything isn't

Comment: So, are you saying that you have one filter $h_1$, and you want to run multiple versions of it, or multiple other filters _in parallel_?  Or are you trying to do something else.

Comment: I want to compute $L$ outputs of _one_ filter at once. After more research, I believe this is called a "block implementation" of a recursive filter?

Comment: _Multiple versions_ of one filter, or do you just want $x_1 = x_2 = \cdots$?

Comment: And are these filters cascaded, as your math seems to indicate, or independent?

Comment: The same filter

Comment: Well, then it's easy.  Just _duplicate the one output to as many as you want_.  Or, you really don't mean "the same filter" and **you need to clarify**.